# Using the ratio test in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

I have calculated the Taylor series for  $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$ centered at $x=0$ with some help and have gotten the following,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n$$

However now I am trying to find the values of $x$ for which this series converges. my thinking here was to use the ratio test,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{n}{x^n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{xn}{n+1}\right|=|x|$$

so then by the ratio test it diverges when $x<-1,x>1$, and converges when $-1<x<1$

Looking at $-1,1$ the ratio test is inconclusive so, when $x=1$ it converges because the series is a convergent alternating series, however when $x=-1$ it diverges because it is just $-1$ multiplied by a divergent p series, as $p=1$

I was not sure if this logic is correct, I get messed up sometimes when the ratio test limit turns out to be $|x|$

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio so then what values of x make the series converge? $x\in R$?

Comment: The values of $x$ such that $|x|$ is smaller than the radius of convergence (i.e. $1$), by the very definition of *radius of convergence*.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio so then how do I show the radius of convergence then? I thought I had to use the ratio test to show that

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio When did he say he wanted the radius of convergence?

Comment: yeah that's what I'm confused about, I was wondering why he was mentioning radius of convergence not convergence

Comment: I will say, his conclusion that your conclusion is right is right :-)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But what's wrong with checking the boundaries if you want to determine if the power series is convergent at those values?  I think his approach was correct.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt so you believe my workings are correct?

Comment: @fr14 Yes, they are fine.